# GTM OAuth for IOS not working with Grails OAuth 2 provider

Tags: grails, oauth, gtm-oauth2

I am currently working on an IOS app and I want to use OAuth to authenticate this app with a Grails system we have in place. The grails system has a OAuth2 provider setup using the plugin at the link below:

```
https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider
```

The OAuth provider is setup and it does work as I have tested the URL's shown below and I do get an authorisation code as expected once the access has been granted:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/app/
```

The issue I am having is that when I use the GTM OAuth plugin for IOS from google I have set it up as follows:

```
static NSString *const kMyClientID = @"1";
static NSString *const kMyClientSecret = @"secret";
static NSString *const kKeychainItemName = @"systemKeychain";

- (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)systemAuth
{

    // Set the token URL to the system token endpoint.
    NSURL *tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.systemurl.co.uk/oauth/token"];

    // Set a bogus redirect URI. It won't actually be used as the redirect will
    // be intercepted by the OAuth library and handled in the app.
    NSString *redirectURI = @"http://www.systemurl.co.uk/";

    GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth;
    auth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication authenticationWithServiceProvider:@"SYSTEM API"
                                                             tokenURL:tokenURL
                                                          redirectURI:redirectURI
                                                             clientID:kMyClientID
                                                         clientSecret:kMyClientSecret];

    return auth;
}

- (void)authorize:(NSString *)service
{
    GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [self systemAuth];

    // Prepare the Authorization URL. We will pass in the name of the service
    // that we wish to authorize with.
    NSURL *authURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.systemurl.co.uk/oauth/authorize"]];

    // Display the authentication view
    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;
    viewController = [ [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithAuthentication:auth
                                                                  authorizationURL:authURL
                                                                  keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                          delegate:self
                                                                  finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
    [viewController setBrowserCookiesURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.systemurl.co.uk/"]];

    // Push the authentication view to our navigation controller instance
    [ [self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}


- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                 error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error != nil)
    {
        // Authentication failed
        UIAlertView *alertView = [ [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authorization Failed"
                                                             message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else
    {
        // Authentication succeeded

        // Assign the access token to the instance property for later use
        self.accessToken = auth.accessToken;

        // Display the access token to the user
        UIAlertView *alertView = [ [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authorization Succeeded"
                                                             message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Access Token: %@", auth.accessToken]
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

The issue is when I run the code above it redirects me to the system fine and I log in, then the page comes up for me to grant access to this app and I click "Authorize" and the app shows me an alert view with an error 500 in it.

So I went back to the Grails system and looked at the logs to see what happened and I noticed the url being passed in by the app was:

```
"GET /oauth/authorize?client_id=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.systemurl.co.uk%2F&response_type=code HTTP/1.1" 302 -

"GET /oauth/authorize?client_id=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.systemurl.co.uk%2F&response_type=code HTTP/1.1" 200 6923

"POST /oauth/authorize?client_id=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.systemurl.co.uk%2F&response_type=code HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

and the error 500 message is shown below from the system:

```
2014-03-24 08:25:53,081 [http-8080-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NoSuchClientException occurred when processing request: [POST] /oauth/token - parameters:
client_secret: secret
grant_type: authorization_code
redirect_uri: http://www.systemurl.co.uk/
code: 4bf5Se
client_id: 1
No client with requested id: testing. Stacktrace follows:
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.NoSuchClientException: No client with requested id: testing
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:179)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Now the error above would suggest to me that for some reason the username is being used as a client id somehow and I don't know why, as the username and password are "testing" on the grails system.

Can anyone please offer any advise on why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance

---

****EDIT************

---

I have debugged the HTTP requests being sent and the below is the RAW request being sent to get the token:

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.systemurl.co.uk
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Language: en-us
Cookie: JSESSIONID=70EB045C21084E166A34EDA88FE155C8.28151
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 130
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: gtm-oauth2 com.test.OAuthGTM/1.0

client_id=1&client_secret=secret&code=VaYn8M&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.systemurl.co.uk%2F
```

Comment: I have added more detail above :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: "client_id=public", then it works

The long answer:

If you debug through the code, you'll find out that the exception is thrown in InMemoryClientDetailsService.

In Grails Version 2.2.4 the code looks something like this

```
private Map<String, ? extends ClientDetails> clientDetailsStore = new HashMap<String, ClientDetails>();

  public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId) throws OAuth2Exception {
    ClientDetails details = clientDetailsStore.get(clientId);
    if (details == null) {
      throw new InvalidClientException("Client not found: " + clientId);
    }
    return details;
  }
```

In the Map clientDetailsStore is only one value which is "public"